# How do I control who can embed my site's embeddable content?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

Here's a simple example of my HTML file, `embed.html`:

```
<div id="embed_content"> Hello, I am special content on the embed.html file. How are you? </div>
```

I'd like to be able to control who can embed that onto their page -- that is, to grant permission on who can use it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering based on the HTTP_REFERER header, but generally speaking, anything you publish on the Internet can be copied or embedded by anyone else. Your only recourse is copyright litigation.

Comment: Where can I read more about filtering based on the HTTP_REFERER (and really, on that subject in general)? And would it make it that much harder for someone to embed content without permission?

Comment: It will make it a little bit harder. As I said originally, generally speaking, anything you publish on the internet can be copied or embedded by anyone else.First Google result for "apache htaccess referer": http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

Answer (score 0):

Unless your content is in a private place it is very difficult to control where it ends up or who has access to it without some pretty complicated server-side rules. `iframe`s are not all that discerning...

Comment: Is there any service available that does something like that? As in, somehow put the target somewhere private and allow me to choose who can embed it?

Comment: This would usually have to be something you'd have to custom program, using either a [PHP check](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) to verify the referrer, or some combination of use with the .htaccess file to [restrict access](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/).